# How to create custom operator class that uses gin indexing in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I created a lot of custom functions and operators in postgresql, and i want to create operator class for them all, and i want to use gin indexing for them. I don't think that i understood postgres documentation well, because i can't get it working. Does anybody have an idea how to do that? Specifically, how to add gin indexing. I tried to just make an operator class and add USING gin, but when i run it through the analize, it says that it doesn't use index search.

Kind regards

EDIT:
I created operators that will do a deep jsonb search by the key, value pair that you provided. They will treat all values as dates, so that you can search in a manner of <, >, =, !=. For those operators, i created an operator class
`CREATE OPERATOR CLASS operatorClassName FOR TYPE jsonb`
`USING GIN as`
`OPERATOR 1 operatorSymbol (jsonb,jsonb),`
`OPERATOR 2 operatorSymbol (jsonb,jsonb),`
`OPERATOR 3 operatorSymbol (jsonb,jsonb),`
`OPERATOR 4 operatorSymbol (jsonb,jsonb)`
And when i ran explain, it says that it used sequential scan instead of index.
What did i do wrong?

EDIT2:

```
CREATE OPERATOR CLASS custom_jsonb_dates_operators FOR TYPE jsonb
USING gin AS
OPERATOR 1 #>? (jsonb, jsonb),
OPERATOR 2 #<? (jsonb, jsonb),
OPERATOR 3 #=? (jsonb, jsonb),
OPERATOR 4 #!=? (jsonb, jsonb);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generic_jsonb_search(
entityObject jsonb,
filterObject jsonb
)
RETURNS boolean
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $$
DECLARE rec record; 
BEGIN
FOR rec in 
    SELECT key, value
    FROM jsonb_each_text(filterObject) as each(key, value)
LOOP
    IF (
        (WITH RECURSIVE jsonb_key_value_merge(key, value) AS (
        SELECT t.key, t.value
        FROM jsonb_each(entityObject) as t

        UNION ALL

        SELECT t.key, t.value
        FROM jsonb_key_value_merge, jsonb_each(CASE
        WHEN jsonb_typeof(jsonb_key_value_merge.value) <> 'object' THEN '{}' :: JSONB
        ELSE jsonb_key_value_merge.value
        END) as t
        )
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM jsonb_key_value_merge t
        where jsonb_typeof(t.value) <> 'object' 
         AND t.value::date > (rec.value)::date AND rec.key = t.key) = 0
    )
    THEN
        RETURN FALSE;
    END IF;
END LOOP;
RETURN TRUE;
END
$$
```

Comment: You have to describe exactly what you did and what your intention is. We can help to find and solve the problem, but we cannot deliver a tutorial about extending PostgreSQL indexing.

Comment: You're right. I edited the post, hope that clears things up a bit

Comment: Did you `SET enable_seqscan = off;`?

Comment: Yes, and it still uses sequential scan

Comment: Perhaps you can add the *exact* `CREATE OPERATOR CLASS` statement and the query to the question.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I edited once again

Comment: Thanks. But I cannot see a query involving one of the new operators in the function code, so I still need to see the query where it fails. Also, the `CREATE INDEX` would be good to know. I don't see why you posted that function definition.

Comment: No, thank you very much for trying to help! I found my problem, when creating index, i wasn't using operator class that i created. Only problem is that i now lack support functions. I guess that i have to implement overlap, contains, is contained by and equals, but i'm not sure how to do that. I can't find any examples online how one should implement it. Do you maybe have some sources?

Comment: Once again, i have to thank you for your help. I was able to solve my problem by using postgres's jsonb operator for the support functions